# Excel cell number format

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010

Is there any way to define an Excel number format with variable decimal places(as much as was entered), but at least 2 (2 is minimum).

- 0          -> 0.00
- 0.1        -> 0.10
- 0.001      -> 0.001
- 534.1      -> 534.10
- 999.334543 -> 999.334543

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you should do:

1. Highlight the entire column.
2. Right click and select format cells
3. Under Number click Custom.
4. Enter `0.00############` as the number format.

This allows you to store decimals like you asked but if the numbers get large you will start losing decimal places. You should read [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/78113). Excel isn't great for storing floating point number.